# how to define custom generic convertor in c#

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I want to make a converter class for myself where I want to declare a function to convert an object of one type to the other type.

For eg, if there are two classes -

```
class A
{
     private int ID {get;set;}
     private string Name  {get;set;}
}

class B
{
     private int ID {get;set;}
     private string Name {get;set;}
     private string Address {get;set;}
}
```

I have declared my class method like this -

```
  T2 Convert<T1, T2>(T1 t1_object)
    {
         A obj1 = (A)t1_object;
         T2 obj2; 

// ... some logic here where properties of t1_object are copied to obj2 (which will be of type B class)....

         return obj2;      
    }
```

Any help will be great.

thanks!

Comment: If you're immediately casting it to `A`, why is `T1` a generic parameter?

Comment: Are you actually getting an error or just looking for suggestions? The approach above will work (have not confirmed the code, just the process) and without involving additional dependancies is a workable solution.

Comment: @Chris - I am getting an error regarding type conversion for T2.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look into [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted devdigital's AutoMapper suggestion, but also wanted to suggest considering refactoring your classes to inherit from a base class, if possible.  Thus your conversion/casting will be super simple.

Answer (score 0):

I upvotet too on the AutoMapper solution, and a viable alternative is [ValueInjecter](http://ttp://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation), maybe a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create simple universal converter.

One way - Use reflection. You can convert objects automaticly. But it's not so simple. You'll have to write some code.

Another way - You can use very simple converter. But you have to describe convertion  rules for every case. Commonly no need to write a lot of code for convertion. Here is example for your case

```
public static class ConvertExtension //exstension for convertion
{
    //automatic convertion
    //later you define in lambda wich data needs to be converted
    public static T Convert<S, T>(this S source, Action<S, T> convert)
        where S : class
        where T : class
    {
        T target = System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        convert(source, target);
        return target;
    }

    //convert data defined in interface
    //you need copy all fields manually
    public static T Convert<T>(this IData source)
        where T : IData
    {
        T target = System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        target.ID = source.ID;
        target.Name = source.Name;

        return target;
    }
}

public interface IData //Describe common properties
{
    int ID {get; set;}
    string Name {get; set;}
}

class A : IData //Interface already implemented. You just mark classes with interface
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class B : IData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

//example
A a = new A();
B b1 = a.Convert<B>();
B b2 = a.Convert<A, B>((s, t) => t.ID = s.ID);
```